# What is the form parameter name to pass for a custom field of a group in Kademi?

Tags: user-registration, kademi

I've added a custom field to a group in Kademi. Now I want to populate it from my signup page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

the parameter name should be same with custom field name. Such as you have custom field like `gender`. The form parameter name should be `gender`.